# Calculating the percentage of the area that a polygon covers a cell in a raster in QGIS

Tags: polygon, shapefile, qgis, gis, grib

I'm having trouble with using QGIS.

I have a GRIB file containing meteorlogical data, this is loaded in QGIS as rasterdata if I'm not mistaken.

I also have a shape-file containing a polygon, describing regions within the area covered in the GRIB file.

What I need to know, is how many % of a raster-cell is covered by a region within the polygon. I'm using QGIS.

What I have done so far, is I rasterized the polygon, and used zonal statistics to calculate the SUM and COUNT on the shape-file, and then used the field calculator to calculate the percentage covered. This does not seem to provide the result I hoped for.

Can anyone push me in the right direction?